# ODE for deflection of an elastic rod

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The following example is taken from the book *Fundamentals of Differential Equations* (by Nagle et al.):

Given the differential equation
$$
y''''(x)-k^2y''(x)=q(x),\quad 0<x<1
$$
for the deflection $y(x)$ of an elastic rod under a load $q(x)$ and subject to a constant axial force proportional to $k^2$.

(a) Show that a general solution can be written in the form
\begin{align*}
y(x)&=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^{kx}+C_4e^{-kx}+\frac{1}{k^2}\int q(x)x\,dx-\frac{x}{k^2}\int q(x)\,dx\\
&\quad +\frac{e^{kx}}{2k^3}\int q(x)e^{-kx}\,dx-\frac{e^{-kx}}{2k^3}\int q(x)e^{kx}\,dx
\end{align*}
(b) Show that the general solution in (a) can be rewritten in the form
\begin{align*}
y(x)&=c_1+c_2x+c_3e^{kx}+c_4e^{-kx}\\
&\quad +\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^xq(s)(s-x)\,ds-\frac{1}{k^3}\int_0^xq(s)\sinh[k(s-x)]\,ds
\end{align*}
(c) How does the form of the solution in (b) change when the integral is to be taken over the interval $x\leq s\leq 1$ instead?

I know how to answer (a), but (b) and (c) are not clear. Perhaps I am overcomplexifying the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: See [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\int f(x) dx$ denotes a primitive $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. Similarly, one can write $$F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^x f(s) ds$$
To see this, use the fundamental theorem of calculus, to take the derivative with respect to $x$. $$F'(x)-0=f(x)$$
Now just replace everywhere $\int f(x) dx $ by $\int_0^x f(s) ds$:
\begin{align*}
y(x)&=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^{kx}+C_4e^{-kx}+\frac{1}{k^2}\int q(x)x\,dx-\frac{x}{k^2}\int q(x)\,dx\\
&\quad +\frac{e^{kx}}{2k^3}\int q(x)e^{-kx}\,dx-\frac{e^{-kx}}{2k^3}\int q(x)e^{kx}\,dx\\&=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^{kx}+C_4e^{-kx}+\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^x q(s)s\,ds-\frac{x}{k^2}\int_0^x q(s)\,ds\\
&\quad +\frac{e^{kx}}{2k^3}\int_0^x q(s)e^{-ks}\,ds-\frac{e^{-kx}}{2k^3}\int_0^x q(s)e^{ks}\,ds
\end{align*}
Now grouping the first two integrals and the last two integrals you get
\begin{align*}
y(x)&=C_1+C_2x+C_3e^{kx}+C_4e^{-kx}+\frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^x q(s)(s-x)\,ds\\
&\quad +\frac{1}{2k^3}\int_0^x q(s)\left(e^{kx}e^{-ks}-e^{-kx}e^{ks}\right)\,ds\end{align*}
Then just use the expression for $\sinh$ to get the answer in part b.

For part c, in a similar way, just use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: Thanks. So strictly speaking replace $\int f(x)\,dx$ by $\int_0^xf(s)\,ds+F(0)$, but since here the $F(0)$ terms cancel just use $\int_0^xf(s)\,ds$?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Again thanks. So for (c) one should then replace $\int f(x)\,dx$ by $-\int_x^1f(s)\,ds+F(1)$, because $F(x)=\int f(x)\,dx~\Rightarrow~F'(x)=f(x)~\Rightarrow~\int_x^1F'(s)\,ds=\int_x^1f(s)\,ds$ and so $F(1)-F(x)=\int_x^1f(s)\,ds=-\int_1^xf(s)\,ds$ verifying that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: But what is $F(1)$? This question (c) is just the killer.

Comment: It does not matter. $F(1)$ is just a number. So when you take the derivative it will disappear

Comment: Right, I tried to solve (c) today by using the substitution I mentioned above. I could not manage to find a correct answer. What I obtain is exactly the same expression as the one given on the interval $0\leq s\leq x$, where only the limits of integration are as asked for in (c).

Comment: Take equation in b. Add and subtract $\int_x^1$ for each integral from $0$ to $x$. $$\int_0^x+\int_x^1-\int_x^1=\int_0^1-\int_x^1$$The integral from $0$ to $1$ is a constant